# GCP - can't SSH into VM from console - Error updating SSH keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I can't ssh into my VM, the firewall is open with port 22, my IP, and IAP IP range, I'm the owner of the project, so I go to the serial port to find out why.

I just found those error logs, but I don't quite understand all of them.

```
GCEGuestAgent Error non_windows_accounts.go:158: Error updating SSH keys for {USER}: mkdir /home/{USER}/.ssh: no such file or directory.
```

```
OSConfigAgent Warning: Error waiting for task (attempt 1 of 10): rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = 502:Bad Gateway
OSConfigAgent Warning: Error waiting for task (attempt 1 of 10): rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I just did some tests. I found where is the problem which is the VM is missing the directory and the guest agent is not able to make a new directory . Therefore, the approach is to create manually a path with /home/{USER}/.ssh

After that, try to ssh into VM again, you would work well. and you will see the `/home/{USER}/.ssh/authorized_keys` this file.

I don't know why the guest agent was not able to [mkdir](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/guest-agent/blob/792fce795218633bcbde505fb3457a0b24f26d37/google_guest_agent/non_windows_accounts.go#L411) the folder. But this approach works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found some Groups conversation with your same issue ["Unable to SSH to instance"](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/iGKqGtPcLvM?pli=1), seems your error is from the guest agent.

And also if the first resolution step is not working, try this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/ssh#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20You,to%20the%20VM) Metadata-managed SSH connections to change linux username, and creates an ephemeral SSH key pair.