# Google Cloud not managing users/SSH in VMs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

We have upgraded Debian distribution in Google Cloud instance and it seems GCloud cannot manage the users and their SSH keys in the instance anymore.

I have installed following tools:

- google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring/now 1.2-499050965 all
- google-cloud-sdk/cloud-sdk-bullseye,now 412.0.0-0 all
- google-compute-engine-oslogin/google-compute-engine-bullseye-stable,now 1:20220714.00-g1+deb11 amd64
- google-compute-engine/google-compute-engine-bullseye-stable,now 1:20220211.00-g1 all
- google-guest-agent/google-compute-engine-bullseye-stable,now 1:20221109.00-g1 amd64

1. I cannot connect through the UI. It gets stuck on "Transfering SSH keys to the instance". The "troubleshooting" says that everything is fine.
2. When trying to connect via `gcloud compute ssh` it dies with

   > permission denied (publickey)
3. I still have access to the instance with some other user, but no new users are created and no SSH keys transferred.

What else am I missing?

EDIT:

> Have you added the SSH key to Project metadata or Instance metadata? If its instance metadata, is project level ssh key blocked?

I haven't added any metadata.

> Does your user account has necessary permission in the project to SSH to the instance (e.g Owner, Editor or Compute Instance Admin IAM role)?

Yes this worked correctly until the debian upgrade to bookworm. I could see all the google-cloud related packages were remove and I had to install them.

> Are you able to SSH to the instance using ssh client e.g Putty?If yes, you need to make sure Google account manager daemon is running on the instance.

I can nicely SSH with accounts which were active on the machine BEFORE the Debian upgrade. These account already have `.ssh` directory correctly set up and working. New google users cannot login.

> Try `gcloud beta compute ssh --zone ZONE INSTANCE_NAME --project PROJECT`

This works only for users active before the Debian upgrade.

> If yes, you need to make sure Google account manager daemon is running on the instance.

I installed the `google-compute-engine-oslogin` package which was missing, but it seems it has no effect and new users still cannot login.

EDIT2:

When connecting to serial console, it gets stuck on: `csearch-dev google_guest_agent[2839775]: ERROR non_windows_accounts.go:158 Error updating SSH keys for gke-495d6b605cf336a7b160: mkdir /home/gke-495d6b605cf336a7b160/.ssh: no such file or directory.` - the same issue, **SSH keys are never transferred into the instance**.

Comment: Check the similar [SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/1050886/google-cloud-permission-denied-publickey/1051945#1051945) which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hm that solves a different problem. As I mention, the "Troubleshooting" shows nothing. This is specifically about transferring the SSH keys into the instance.

Comment: To investigate the issue further can you provide the following info:
1. Have you added the SSH key to Project metadata or Instance metadata?If its instance metadata, is project level ssh key blocked?
2. Does your user account has necessary permission in the project to SSH to the instance (e.g Owner, Editor or Compute Instance Admin IAM role)?
3. Are you able to SSH to the instance using ssh client e.g Putty?If yes, you need to make sure [Google account manager daemon](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages#daemons) is running on the instance.

Comment: Can you try running this gcloud command in the Cloud Shell ? :

gcloud beta compute ssh --zone ZONE INSTANCE_NAME --project PROJECT

Comment: I updated the questions with answers to your question.

Comment: Apart from Answer also suggest checking out "The SSH connection failed after you upgraded the VM's kernel. A VM might experience a kernel panic after a kernel update, causing the VM to become inaccessible".  [troubleshooting ssh](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors) for more info or the [SSH from the browser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser) document.

Comment: The instance is running and there is no kernel panic. I can connect with old users as I write above.

Comment: Please review EDIT2 in my Answer, which may assist in resolving your issue.

Comment: I have read the EDIT2, but I am not sure you read what I wrote. The machine is booting and working as expected. I can SSH into the isntance with some old user accounts. But NO new SSH keys are transferred into the instance by the Google Cloud agent. The Google Cloud agent is installed and I cannot see any errors of it.

Answer (score 1):

**There are a few things you can do troubleshoot the Permission denied (publickey) error message :**

To start, you must ensure that you have properly authenticated yourself with gcloud using an IAM user with the [compute instance admin role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam). You can do that by running `gcloud auth login [USER]` then `try gcloud compute ssh` again.

You can also verify that the Linux Guest Environment scripts are properly installed and running. Please refer to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment) for information about [validating](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#wgei), [updating](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#update-guest), or [manually installing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#installing_guest_environment) the guest environment.

Another possibility is that the private key was lost or that we have a mismatched keypair. To force gcloud to generate a new SSH keypair, you must first move `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` and `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub` if present, for example:

```
mv ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub.old
mv ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.old
```

Once that is done, you may then try `gcloud compute ssh [INSTANCE-NAME]` again, a new keypair should be created and a public key will be added to the SSH keys metadata.

Refer to [Sunny-j](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814024/sunny-j) and [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52124642/google-compute-engine-cant-ssh-to-it-after-debian-upgrade) to review the serial-port logs of the affected instance for possible clues on the issue. Also refer to [Resolving getting locked out of a Compute Engine](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b) for more information.

**Edit1:**
Refer to this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73273880/gcp-cant-ssh-into-vm-from-console-error-updating-ssh-keys) and [Troubleshooting using the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console) which helps to resolve your error.

**EDIT2:**
Maybe you have git-all installed. Cloud-init and virtually every step of the booting process are disrupted as a result of this, as the older SysV init system takes its place. You are unable to SSH into your instance as a result of this.

Check out these potential solutions to the above problem:

1.Try using git instead of git-all.

2.If git-all is necessary, use apt install --no-install-recommends -y git-all to prevent the installation of recommendations.

**Finally :** If you were previously able to SSH into the instance with a particular SSH key for new users, either the SSH daemon was not running or was otherwise broken, or you somehow removed that SSH key. It would appear that you damaged this machine during the upgrade.

Why is this particular VM instance required? Does it contain significant data? If this is the case, you can turn it off, mount its disk with a new VM instance, and copy that data off.( I'd recommend build another machine running these services from latest snapshot or scratch and start using that instead).

You should probably move to a new machine if it runs a service: There is no way to tell what still works and what doesn't, even if you are able to access the instance.

Comment: I am correctly authorized and I can access all other resources. This unfortunately happens also from Google Cloud UI, when clicking on "SSH" in the instance detail. I tried to move the `google_compute_engine` keys with no effect.

Comment: When connecting to serial console, it gets stuck on: `csearch-dev google_guest_agent[2839775]: ERROR non_windows_accounts.go:158 Error updating SSH keys for gke-495d6b605cf336a7b160: mkdir /home/gke-495d6b605cf336a7b160/.ssh: no such file or directory.` - the same issue, SSH keys are never transferred into the instance.

Comment: Please check the edit in the answer and also try adding the firewall rule explicitly for IAP server with 22 and xxxx port.

Comment: But as I mentioned, there is no issue with FW as I can easily SSH into the machine for previously created users. Also, there was no change in the firewall, only the Debian version was upgraded.

Comment: Please refer to this similar [SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/1041460/lost-ssh-access-to-google-cloud-vm/1065453#1065453), which may help to resolve your issue.